# Does the Havtacha in the Igeres Haramban apply to everyone?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, segulah

I was wondering if what the Ramban writes in the end of the letter to his son

> ובכל יום שתקראנה יענוך מן השמים כאשר יעלה על לבך לשאול עד עולם

was specifically for his son, or does this apply to anyone who reads the Igeres?

I am looking for an answer that draws from real sources, or a direct quote from a Talmid Chacham.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to this quote so that other can have a look?

Comment: Every place I've seen the letter printed has the same line quoted from a book "מעולפת ספירים" that it applies to everyone.  From the letter itself I don't see why it's a "havtacha" and not a wish, or for that matter, why this particular line has become more famous than ומי כה' אלהינו בכל קראנו אליו

Comment: .@b a 1)Can you provide a link to that sefer 2)i think the reason why we see it as a havtach is that the Ramban clearly writes if you do x then יענוך which means "they will answer you", which to me sounds pretty definitive.

Comment: 3)the pasuk ומי כה' אלהינו בכל קראנו אליו does not necessarily mean that Hashem will fulfill our wishes. As a side note there are very few times where there are so called "Guaranteed results" to our tefilot, one particular one which comes to mind is from the Ari Hakadosh where it is brought down in his name that one who has a certain kavanah during the word "איה" in kedusha of Yamim Noraim can daven for on of three things "ומובטח שלא תחזור תפילתו ריקן"

Comment: There's a book by that name on HebrewBooks (search without ו), I'm not sure where in it. Also, I don't get pinged unless you write @ba without a space

Answer (score 2):

I had the same doubt a few weeks back and asked Rabbi Shimcha Bart at Chabad.org, His answer was that there is a machloket here. Some great Talmidei chachamim would say this applies to only his son and some that this applies to everyone.

In my humble opinion, I say this would effect us too. Iggeret HaRaMBaN has so many good mussar to follow that this could certainly bring about many blessings if one carries them out everyday. :)